# bash script для создания папок

Tags: linux, bash

Есть множество папок **dir1, dir2, dir3** и тд, общее количество - 100-200, к примеру. Нужен скрипт, который создаст около них папки типа **dir1fold, dir2fold, dir3fold**(грубо говоря, берётся название предыдущей папки и добавляется префикс **fold**) и, в идеале, перенесёт каждый **dir** в свой **dirfold**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for dir in *; do
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        newdir="${dir}fold"    
        mkdir "$newdir"
        mv "$dir" "$newdir"
    fi
done
```